# Physical meaning of impulsive boundary condtion

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00264464?LI=true), the author study a wave motion initiated by a delta at the interface of two media.

A model problem is :
$$ \partial_{tt}^2\, u(t,x,y) = c^2_+  \Delta u(t,x,y) \quad \text{in}\; x>0, \,y\in \mathbb{R} $$ 
$$ \partial_{tt}^2\, v(t,x,y) = c^2_- \Delta v(t,x,y) \quad \text{in}\; x<0, \,y\in \mathbb{R} $$ 
with zero initial conditions for $u$ and $v$ and boundary conditions:
$$ 
u - v =f(t,y) \qquad \text{and} \qquad  \partial_x u - \partial_x v = g(t,y)
$$

> Assume $u$ and $v$ are homogeneous and infinite elastic membranes:
>
> What is the physical meaning of the following three cases?
>
> 1. $f = \delta(t)\delta(y)\;$ and $\;g = 0$
> 2. $f = 0\;$ and $\;g = \delta(t)\delta(y)$
> 3. $f=\delta(t)\delta(x)\;$ and $\;g = \delta(t)\delta(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: ($f=\delta(t)\delta(y),g=0$)

Imagine the functions $u(x,y,t)$ and $v(x,y,t)$ as sheets, each covering half the plane. At $t=0$ the center point of the $u$-sheet is pinched extremely highly upward extremely quickly, and then is just as quickly slammed down again.

Case 2: ($f=0,g=\delta(t)\delta(y)$)

Using the same sheet analogy, at $t=0$ the center point of the $u$-sheet is pinched upward by 1 unit and then stays at 1 unit for the remainder of time.

Case 3: ($f=g=\delta(t)\delta(y)$)

Using the same sheet analogy, at $t=0$ the center point of the $u$-sheet is pinched extremely highly upward extremely quickly, and then is just as quickly slammed back down to 1 unit, then stays at 1 unit for the remainder of time.

Comment: Also, the paper is behind a paywall.